# Get 403 only on a single machine

Tags: website, browsing

I was in the middle of doing some site maintenance when my website started giving me 403 errors. But... it was only on this one machine, no matter the browser. I emailed my host and they said everything seemed to be normal on their end, and my other computers accessed the site just fine. Emptied my cache and not sure what else to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 means Forbidden.

A common cause of this is that the web server does not have the proper permission to access the file you are trying to tell it to give you.

Did you accidentally change the permissions of a file or folder during your maintenance?

Also, did you accidentally delete or modify any `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Nope, just working with stylesheets. If it was a real 403, it would just be a blanket denial of access, right? Because I can pull up the address on two machines right now at the same time, have one of them access it, and the other show the error. I run WP, so maybe I got hacked, but still... should be showing the 403 across the board in that case.

Comment: Well, it does appear that I got hacked, and somehow the error only applied to the computer that was editing it at the time. (Can't wait to get rid of WP.) Just replaced .htaccess and everything's good.

Comment: Login retry lockout can be set to throw a deny line in the .htaccess for the ip address of the "attacker". Flub your login too many times and lose access.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem: A website returned 403 - but only for certain machines. The reason was a faulty AAAA-Record which was no problem for most users as they connected via IPv4.

The 403 message came from the target the AAAA-Record pointed to: There was just no content in the html folder.